# Replace underscore with hyphen while writing script in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm writing pipeline in Jenkins. My code looks something like below:

```
void someFun(){
sh '''
VAR='a_b_c_d'
TEMPVAR=$VAR | tr '_' '-'
echo "With hyphens $TEMPVAR-blah-blah"
echo "With underscores $VAR"
'''
}

stage{
someFun()
}
```

All I want to achieve is a way to replace underscores from 1st variable and use its value in 2nd variable. Also. I'm not intending to mutate VAR. And I want to store the value, not just print it.
When I'm using this above approach, I'm getting **TEMPVAR** empty.

What I'm trying to possible to achieve is possible? If yes, what is the way to achieve it?
I read multiple posts but couldn’t find any helpful:(

Comment: Do you try to make it in groovy using the replace method or do you really need to do it in shell ?

Comment: Using groovy to do that would be less performant and a [bad practice](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/pipeline-best-practices/#making-sure-to-use-groovy-code-in-pipelines-as-glue)

Comment: For a trivial task like this, I really have to respectfully disagree.

Comment: @fmdaboville, I need to do it in shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in many ways, like with:

- `tr`, but in this case you need to use an additional shell:

  ```
  TEMPVAR="$(echo "$VAR" | tr _ -)"
  ```
- or even better with string substitution:

  ```
  TEMPVAR="${VAR//_/-}"
  ```

Comment: Thank you, Marco! Just a stupid question over here. In the 1st approach, will it also print value of VAR as we're echoing it?

Comment: You are welcome! No, the output is piped and stays inside the subshell.

Comment: @marco-luzzara, This really deserves an explanation as to why it's not working as OP expected in the post, rather than just "here's the answer and an alternative.